# How would I go about tracking flash videos without using javascript?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, google-analytics, web-analytics

There are cases where shipping javascript code with your flash video is not an option. One of these cases is when you've bought space on a website to place your ad banner. In those cases I want to use the 1x1 pixel image tracking method on Google Analytics or Yahoo Web Analytics to track the amount of views on my banner.

I have heard that flash blocks any attempt to load data from a third party host (frankly I don't see why they would do that) which presents a problem. I would love a solution.

I can picture several methods and their downsides

- I could host the banner on my own server, counting the downloads. Unfortunately this would prove to be a tremendous load on my server when possibly millions of downloads would happen per day.
- I could write a PHP script, hosting it on my own server, that when requested tracks a page view in GA or YWA. I could place a crossdomain.xml file on my server allowing the flash banner to request my script using a Loader. Unfortunately, the problem of server load still exists as my private server probably can't handle millions of requests per day.

Possible solutions are other tracking hosts that allow for flash cross domain file requests, or perhaps a method I haven't thought of.

**Summary: The challenge here is to be able to track the number of views on a flash video without using any javascript. The problem is the sheer amount of load this would put on my own servers if I were to track using my server as a proxy. The best solution would be a tracking service using crossdomain.xml**

Comment: Have you attempted to load the Google analytic tracker .gif with Flash? The only server you need to worry about cross domain restriction is the server you are requesting. Not where the SWF is hosted.

Comment: I know, but should I assume google analytics has a crossdomain.xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is something like Google Analytics with in AS3 mode.

> Use this mode if you control the Adobe
>   Flash ActionScript 3 code, but you do
>   not control the hosting environment of
>   your Adobe Flash application. For
>   example, if you are developing Flash
>   content for distribution across many
>   sites, then you would use AS3 mode.
>   AS3 mode is completely independent
>   from the ga.js tracking code and
>   contains all the Analytics tracking
>   functionality. There is no need for a
>   separate ga.js tracking installation
>   with this mode. In addition, AS3 mode
>   uses the Flash storage mechanism to
>   track session information for the
>   visitor.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html#trackingModes

I've used something similar with Omniture SiteCatalyst to track embedded video players.

Comment: I'd mark your answer as correct but I can't seem to get it working. I've confirmed that my flash file loads the gif file from google analytics, but even after 10+ hours I'm not getting any pageviews.

Comment: Ok pardon my previous comment. Google Analytics was unusually slow, but I finally got page views from the flash video. Thanks :-)

Comment: i have been using this tracking mode in games distributed across multiple hosts and it's working out pretty good, referrals aren't very reliable, but other than that i get all the stats i need.